# Background-Image size not working in all browsers

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, positioning, background-image

the weirdest thing just happened, I had a problem I fixed with the footer and I accidently left the %sign after contain in my code. Take a look. My site is usahvacsupply.com

```
html, body{
overflow:auto;
margin: auto;
background-image:url('/images/Testing1/bg2.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position:top center;
-moz-background-size:100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
background-size:contain%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Without the % sign after contain it throws everything off. The % only satisfies for firefox though. Does anyone know a fix for all browsers? IE the % helps but throws off the top level navigation tabs. In chrome it is all out of wack. I'm pretty much baffled here so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Changing contain to 100% makes it fill the entire screen on my end?  Thats what you want right???

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have different background-position rules for the different prefixes.

If you'd like to use 'contain' as a value, try removing the % and then follow suit with the other rules.

```
-moz-background-size: contain;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: no, I just changed it to auto and it does what I want except for the top level nav tabs being shifted out of place when the window is not maximized. Do you see a fix for that?

Comment: The contain would work but it throws off my alignment on the content of the page

Comment: There are a few things going on here. Your use of tables is limiting your ability to properly define your template. I would consider adding a set pixel width on your body or wrapper element. From there I'd analyze how you're styling your table rows and cells, and perhaps remove the first empty cell and orient your navigation to the left. So then it wouldn't slide out of view.

Comment: I think I fixed it by applying a float: left to my div lol in the header!